# R: finding maximum value every two rows in each column

Tags: r, matrix

I want to find maximum value in each column for every 2 rows (say). How to do that in R? For example

```
matrix(c(3,1,20,5,4,12,6,2,9,7,8,7), byrow=T, ncol=3)
```

I want the output like this

```
matrix(c(5,4,20,7,8,9), byrow=T, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way of doing it.

1. Define a vector that contains information about the `groups` you want. In this case, I use `rep` to repeat a sequence of numbers.
2. Then define a helper function to calculate the column maximum of an array — this is a simple `apply` of `max`.
3. finally, use `sapply` with an anonymous function that applies `colMax` to each of your grouped array subsets.

The code:

```
groups <- rep(1:2, each=2)
colMax <- function(x)apply(x, 2, max)
t(
    sapply(unique(groups), function(i)colMax(x[which(groups==i), ]))
)
```

The results:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    4   20
[2,]    7    8    9
```

Comment: @DWin I'm not sure what you have in mind. I **think** that this generalises, as long as you define `groups` correctly. But the OP isn't very clear on exactly what the group definition is, so I left it to the user to define that up-front.

Comment: It was the group definition I was whinging about, and on reflection I think I shouldn't have said anything. I'll delete in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

A one long line:

```
t(sapply(seq(1,nrow(df1),by=2),function(i) apply(df1[seq(i,1+i),],2,max)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option,

```
do.call(rbind, by(m, gl(nrow(m)/2, 2), function(x) apply(x, 2, max)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) tapply(x, # work on each column
       # create groups of 2 vector of proper length:  1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 ....
      rep(1:(length(x)/2), each=2, len=length(x)) 
       max))

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    5    4   20
2    7    8    9
```