# Calculate min, maximum and mean in R

Tags: r

I have data set with 130 rows and two columns. 
I want to calculate the mean, minimum and maximum of every 5 rows of the seconds column using R. By using colMeans and the following command 
`rep(colMeans(matrix(data$Pb, nrow=5), na.rm=TRUE), each=5)` I was able to compute mean for every 5 rows. However i am not able to compute max and min since there is no built in function for the same. I tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921300/r-finding-maximum-value-every-two-rows-in-each-column) for 5 rows instead of 2. However I get an error that `dim(X) must have a positive length.` Can someone please help me understand as to what should I do to fix and compute the above quantities ? My end goal is to plot min,mean, max for every 5 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are looking for function to find the `max` and `min` of each column of `matrix`, `colMaxs` and `colMins` from `matrixStats` can be used.

```
library(matrixStats)
colMaxs(mat)
#[1]  7  8 20

colMins(mat)
#[1] 3 1 7
```

---

But, if this is to find for every 5 rows of dataset columns, use `gl` to create the grouping index for each 5 rows, and then with the help of `by` we get the `colMaxs` or `colMins` or `colMeans`

```
by(data, list(gr=as.numeric(gl(nrow(data), 5, nrow(data)))), 
                 FUN = function(x) colMaxs(as.matrix(x)))
```

The same way, we can find the `colMins` or `colMeans`

```
by(data, list(gr=as.numeric(gl(nrow(data), 5, nrow(data)))),
             FUN = function(x) colMins(as.matrix(x)))

by(data, list(gr=as.numeric(gl(nrow(data), 5, nrow(data)))),
             FUN = function(x) colMeans(as.matrix(x)))
```

---

The above can be done in a compact way with `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>%
    group_by(gr = as.numeric(gl(nrow(.), 5, nrow(.)))) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(min, max, mean))
```

To do the `plot`ting, may be we can extend this with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(gr = as.numeric(gl(nrow(.), 5, nrow(.)))) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(min, max, mean)) %>%
    gather(Var, Val, -gr) %>% 
    separate(Var, into = c("Var1", "Var2")) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=factor(gr), y=Val, fill=Var2)) + 
           geom_bar(stat="identity")+
           facet_wrap(~Var1)
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(c(3,1,20,5,4,12,6,2,9,7,8,7), byrow=T, ncol=3) 
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(Pb = sample(1:9, 42, replace=TRUE), Ps = rnorm(42))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, Thanks for your help. The plotting function can you please simplify it ? I am a novice in R and haven't used it. There are many columns created for each column with mean , min and max values. How can I plot it so that it must look like the answer given by Glen_b [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/plotting-summary-statistics-with-mean-sd-min-and-max) . Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

A nice function for this would be the base `by` function combined with `apply`. Below is an example where you first make a index of the groups for your function:

```
m <- matrix(runif(130*2),130,2)
group <- rep(seq(nrow(m)), each=5, length.out=nrow(m))
res <- by(m, INDICES = group, FUN = function(x){apply(x, MARGIN=2, FUN=max)})
class(res) # "by" class
do.call(rbind, res) # matrix
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.